# Django Email sending SMTP Error, cant send a mail

Tags: python, django, email, smtp, gmail

I am trying to send email within my Django project:

```
# settings.py
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

```
def notify_user(email_address, subject='Subject', message='Some message!') -> None:
    send_mail(
        subject,
        message,
        settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        [email_address],
        fail_silently=False
    )
```

As I know I need to disable this option ([Gmail Security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fblm4.png)), but Gmail don't let me do it.

As a result I got this error:

```
raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials f14-20020a056512360e00b00492bbf7db8asm320697lfs.85 - gsmtp')
```

What can I do? How to disable that option?

Comment: I think you're going to have to use an alternative. See for example: https://medium.com/beingcoders/alternative-to-less-secure-apps-gmail-2022-c1618a9f5efd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google disabled/discontinued the Less Secure App feature as of May 30th, 2022.

As recommended by @MeL, you could use an alternative but you can still use Gmail to send emails using `Django`. You can read this blog *[Mail setup on django using Gmail](https://suhailvs.github.io/blog02.html#mail-setup-on-django-using-gmail)* to help with guiding the setup if you're unfamiliar with setting up [Google App Passwords](https://www.google.com/settings/security).

In addition to that, you'll need to do one last thing to activate the app password to be used by `Django`. You should visit the site https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha, select continue and you're all set.