# gmail smtp not connecting

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, smtp, gmail

so I'm trying to set up my smtp for mail delivery and I decided to use gmail. I've seen the new update concerning the restrictions placed on less secure apps so I went ahead to get A 2FA password but still I'm getting an error.

my settings.py

```
#smtp settings
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.getenv('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv('EMAIL_PASS')
```

The error that it's throwing is:

> TimeoutError at /Shipping/Ship/
> [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Any help please?

Comment: Not sure if that's your internet connection or maybe you didn't set up the DisplayUnlockCaptcha... But you could view this answer to see if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/73422997/15978450.

Comment: @Damoiskii I did everything, still the same error outputted in the python shell