# How to send email on smtp server in django?

Tags: django, email, smtp, gmail

here is m settings.py file

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAL_HOST_USER = 'test.mailed.login@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Google used to have a less-secure apps settings now that it is removed, I am using this alternatively
I obviously went on a google and created a new app and filled it on the EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD
I also enabled two step authentication
Obviously i changed my app password on the above code so no one can see it

I imported send_mail and run the function but it still sending me this error

[error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZOK6.png)

This is exactly what I have done nothing more or nothing less
Every youtube video that I check it is working for all of them, Am I missing an earlier step

Comment: I had the same problem three months ago,now you can't use your real email password ,you have to create an app password for `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` to create an app password you can use this link https://www.getmailbird.com/gmail-app-password/ .let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Email sending SMTP Error, cant send a mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73422664/django-email-sending-smtp-error-cant-send-a-mail)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to generate app password from google app password generator.

after generating the password add the password in SMTP E-Mail settings.

[image]

You can generate password from [here](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords)